# Angular 2 - Error when I execute ng build --prod

Tags: angular

I'm using angular cli to create my angular projects 2.

I had no problem in developing. I always executed npm start and never had error.

However I went to run the command: ng build --prod and he angular cli presented me with several errors.

Errors of type:

That I should declare the variable as public to use in my html, A property did not exist in the class and others.

I do not understand the reason Angular cli not having warned before. Now there are more than 200 errors.

Does anyone know why angular cli have not caught these errors before? Is there any solution for this?

Comment: It's an error produced by AOT compilation and `ng build --prod` executes AOT compilation by default. If you want to set AOT option to true even on dev mode you must do: `ng serve --aot` and it should show errors in development.

Answer (score 1):

You might have declared a variable as private inside a component and are attempting to display it in the UI.
Can the variable modifier be set to public?

Answer (score 0):

Which version of the cli are you using?

> Does anyone know why angular cli have not caught these errors before?

Since some versions is a requirement that variables used in templates should be public. For more information check [this issue in github](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli/issues/5623).

> Is there any solution for this?

You will have to track down those private variables and change them to public.

Answer (score 0):

You have some error either in html or in ts files. Normally compile does not catch those errors. Go to your projects ClientApp folder, open cmd and run ng build --prod. It will show you the errors in html or ts files. Then fix it and publish.